# INFO: fetch-response is unable to open the file

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

INFO: fetch-response is unable to open the file

/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/BD4804E9-CB5C-4724-B18C-A29D0B21B530/Library/Caches/com.newtheatre.production/fsCachedData/837EFB90-7B6D-437A-9428-0F84C1B9A315. Errno: 2

I get this error on a view controller that presents a collection view with cells showing an image and label that is very similar to another view controller showing the same cells but where this does not occur. This error results in blank space where the collection view cell is supposed to display the image and label.

The web suggests that this related to Core Data, but I'm not using Core Data. I'm caching the images, and appears to relate to a failure to retrieve cache (possibly?) but I don't know why I only get this problem with one view controller and not the other.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Make sure you're not doing saving & retrieving on two different threads. If i can see the code of Saving and retrieving i could probably help